# Nested Documents in FaunaDB

Tags: faunadb

I am just starting Fauna and FQL. How do we add a nested document inside another document using the online shell?

This is what I have so far

```
users: [
    {
      userID: "from google",
      userName: "from signup form",
      userEmail: "from signup form form",
      profileimgurl: "maybe from google",
      accessCode: 12345,
      role: "main or secondary. customer will automatically become main."
    },
    {
      userID: "from google",
      userName: "from signup form",
      userEmail: "from signup form form",
      profileimgurl: "maybe from google",
      accessCode: 12345,
      role: "main or secondary. customer will automatically become main."
    }
  ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Fauna stores data in schemaless [Documents](https://docs.fauna.com/fauna/current/api/fql/documents), so you can embed arrays or other objects within the Document's data.  For example, from the shell:

```sh
Create(
  Collection("users"),
  {
    data: { 
      name: "Paul",
      email: "paul@paul.com
      address: {
        country: "United States",
      },
      tags: ["pinball", "camping"]
    }
  }
)
```

Depending on how you need to read and update your documents, it may be appropriate to save data in a separate collection and maintain relationships with [References](https://docs.fauna.com/fauna/current/api/fql/types?lang=javascript#ref).

```sh
Create(
  Collection("public_profiles"),
  {
    data: { 
      name: "Paul",
      tags: ["pinball", "camping"]
    }
  }
)

{
  ref: Ref(Collection("public_profiles"), "307924242117165124"),
  ts: 1629918291110000,
  data: { name: "Paul", tags: ["pinball", "camping"] }
}
```

```sh
Update(
  Ref(Collection("users"), "307924248572638574"),
  {
    data: { 
      tags: null,
      profile: Ref(Collection("public_profiles"), "307924242117165124")
    }
  }
)
```

The Docs have a [Social Graph example](https://docs.fauna.com/fauna/current/tutorials/social_graph) that demonstrates how to create and query relationships.